# Bootstrap 5.0 validation with php where the user already exists in the database

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-5

my registration form has basic validation for html attributes, e.g. type = 'email' etc. They display nicely styled by the new feature in Bootstrap Validation.

The problem occurs when I send the form to PHP. First, the data goes through AJAX to PHP to display errors without refreshing the page, but when checking e.g. if the entered email is already registered with a negative result, my input is still marked as: valid (green highlight). What should I do

**register.php**

```
$success = false;
$error = false;
$mssg = "Error";

if(!isset($_POST['email']) && !isset($_POST['pass'])){
    $mssg = "Inputs are empty";
}else{

    //example result for database
    $used_email = "foo@email.com";

    // example validation
    if($_POST['email'] == $used_email){
        $error = 'email';
        $mssg = "Email is already taken!";
    }else $success=true;
    
        
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('success' => $success, 'error'=> $error, 'mssg' => $mssg));
exit;
```

```js
(function (){
      $("#formregister").on('submit', function(ev){

        const form = $(this);
  
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();
  
        var obj= new Object;
        Object.keys(form[0].getElementsByTagName('input')).filter(function(key) {
          obj[form[0][key].id] = form[0][key].value;
        });
  
        if (this.checkValidity()) {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register.php",
            data: obj,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
              if(!data.success) {
                if(data.error){
                  $("#"+data.error).addClass("is-invalid").focus();
                  $("#"+data.error).next().html(data.mssg);
                }else 
                  $("#result").attr("class", "alert alert-danger").html(data.mssg);
              }else{
                $("#result").html("Success");
                $("#result").attr("class", "alert alert-success");
              }
            }
            });
        }else form.find(":invalid").first().focus();

        form.addClass("was-validated");
      });

})();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<form class="needs-validation" id="formregister" novalidate>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <div class="mt-2">
          <label for="email" class="form-label">E-mail</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">123</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-2">
          <label for="pass" class="form-label">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 justify-content-end d-flex mt-4 mb-2">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
```

If I add **.is-invalid** class during validation, input doesn't change its style to red.

[Issue img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKpQk.png)

Comment: Well, for starters, you should share the PHP code that does the validation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution! The **:invalid** and **:valid** attributes have style advantages over classes, so the **.is-invalid** class must have border attributes with **!imporant** at the end.

For people who will have a similar problem in the future.

Need to add to boostrap.css **.is-invalid and .is-valid** -> **!important**

Comment: Could you please share the working code, as i am not sure where you want to add !important in .css file or in JS code.. it would be nice if you can share the code as have spend considerable time to make form work with BS 5 with validation..

Answer (score 0):

ON the STAYS GREEN issue:

After the server validation you have to change the class of the input with AJAX or PHP to  **.is-invalid**  to get the WRONG red style -   or **.is-valid** for the correct value.

You can give the user additional hints with the **.invalid-feedback** is also supported with these classes.

Exampled can be found here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/#server-side

Formore help we need your PHP code

Update: you are using BS5 BETA.

THE V5.0 is now released.

Get it now and hopefully they fixed the bug.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/

Comment: Did you try to add the  class  is_invalid with Chrome Devtools where you also can debug the AJAX requests?  Not that there is a bug in BS 5.beta

Comment: just check new img on post, 
I think this is a problem from the Boostrap side because it is a BETA version

Comment: Just use the released 5.0 get it on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/

Comment: But your source says you still use the old beta??  https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css